Multi-line subcaption formatting
I need to put 3 images side by side corresponding to 3 graphics with different parameters: I use the subcaption package
For clarity of the graph, I would like to put the parameters in the legends of the subfigures: as I have 3 parameters, I considered a line break with \\ but the result is not very satisfactory.
Do you have an idea to make it a little more satisfactory?
Thanks

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{subcaption}
 \usepackage{siunitx}

\title{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth} % "0.45" donne ici la largeur de l'image
        \centering \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-duck} 
        \caption{$C_a=\qty{1e-1}{\mol \per \l} \\ V_a=\qty{10}{\ml}\\C_b=\qty{8e-2}{\mol\per\l}$}\label{fig:tit_conducti_AFBF_0.1}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~ % ce symbole ajoute un espacement horisontal entre les premières deux images
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-duck} 
        \caption{$C_a=\qty{1e-2}{\mol \per \l} \\ V_a=\qty{10}{\ml}\\C_b=\qty{8e-3}{\mol\per\l}$}\label{fig:tit_conducti_AFBF_0.01}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-duck} 
        \caption{$C_a=\qty{1e-4}{\mol \per \l} \\ V_a=\qty{10}{\ml}\\C_b=\qty{8e-5}{\mol\per\l}$}\label{fig:tit_conducti_AFBF_0.0001}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~
    \caption{Dosage conductimétrique d'un acide fort par une base forte}\label{fig:titrage_conducti_AFBF}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


Try \captionsetup[subfigure]{format=hang}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelsep=newline,justification=centering} would leave more room.
